# How to retain ASP NET Web Api previous request values

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, rest, asp.net-web-api

We Are Developing an API but i'm stuck at how to retain previous request value. For example we have send below message to user's whatsapp.

> Kindly Send reply by option number.
>
> 1. Complaint
> 2. Billing
> 3. Invoices

and user reply back by 1 so the complaint sub menu will be display like this.

> Kindly Send reply by option number.
>
> 1. For New Complaint
> 2. For Complaint List

but how would i know that user has entered in complaint menu option number 1? and how i will pass complaint option number in subsequent APIs.
The question is how do i retain previous value? do i have to use any database side handling or caching if yes then how?

Comment: Hi...Can you try to design the input Json contract in such a way that the "path" or the list (along with the order) of inputs in sent always? May be this could help ?

Comment: @RisingHerc I think it will not work i just only receive numbers and i need to retain this numbers in something. like cache or db

Comment: In that case, if you are using ASP.NET Core, then you have an in-memory cache framework that is lightning fast and simple to use. You can store user-based message history over there. Hope this helps!

Comment: no it is asp net web api 2.0

Comment: at the end of the day, what did they do last week, what occured in the past? Almost for sure you want to save, track, deal with, and maintain this information in a database system. The idea that you going to guess or hope that some web api call you made yesterday, or 2 minutes ago is by some magic act going to be persisted for you is simple the wrong road and approach. You need to design a database to manage and track this type of information, most likly based on their logon ID.  So, be this information as to what was done 2 minutes ago, 2 hours ago, or 2 days ago needs to be saved.